TVS for latch relay driving
I am driving a latch relay with the circuit below.when i drive the latch relay, sometimes mcu flash memory corrupted and some flash data lost, so this causes the mcu malfunction. i assume that there is transient voltage across the relay coils so in my opinion i should get rid of it by using a tvs diode across the coil.In my original circuit there is not any tvs across the coil and 12VDC power line. I just want to know whether this will be a solution or not if I use a TVS diode like below. I am not sure about the bidirectional tvs diode across the relay coil for the protection whole circuit components like mcu and other ICs. I also use the unidirectional tvs on 12VDC power supply line.Can you give advise me about the usage of diodes.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have edited the clarifications in my post.

It should not be required since that part, the LV8548, is designed to handle an inductive (motor) load and you've dealt with the power supply adequately, based on the schematic.
If the corruption happens as a result of the load you are switching with the relay rather than the relay itself (a not atypical situation), then your PCB layout may be the issue.
If it's happening with the relay not switching a load PCB layout could also be the problem, but it would have to be pretty bad. The wires between the chip and the relay should be short and not run near sensitive logic lines. An RC snubber across the coil (eg. 10Ω and 1uF) might be better than a TVS.
As an aside, the English in  that datasheet is a bit dubious or overdramatic for a technical document.. eg. (emphasis added):

Driving control input pin of OUT1 (10pin) and OUT2 (9pin). It combines
with IN2 pin (3pin) and it fights desperately.

We don't usually anthropomorphize what goes on in Mr. Chip's mind.
